# activate/deactivate sonar maven plugin by profile?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I would like to use the Sonar plugin so that it executes only if activated in my Maven profile. Currently Sonar runs on every compile.

The problem is that the build will fail for other team members which do not have the Sonar application installed locally. The pom.xml is checked in so all team members get the same copy including the sonar configuration, but I don't want them to modify it just for the purpose of disabling Sonar (they might inadvertently check their modified copy in).

Please advise how to configure Maven (.m2/settings.xml) and/or pom.xml so that the Sonar feature can be enabled/disabled by a local profile.

Here is the Sonar configuration currently in each project's pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-sonar</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sonar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: My advice would be to not attach the Sonar execution to a Maven phase and even if this is done through a Maven profile. Triggering an analysis of a project with Sonar should be done directly with help of the "sonar:sonar" command and this must be scheduled in your ci engine.

Answer (score 1):

Just include your configuration within a Maven profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
            <!-- Your Sonar config here -->
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then invoke Maven with the profile enabled:
`mvn clean install -Psonar`

As of Maven 2.09 you can automatically enable a plugin based upon the presence of a file. So you could add the following `activation` to the above profile:

```
<activation>
    <file>
        <exists>/full/path/to/sonar/installation</exists>
    </file>
</activation>
```

If absolute paths make you itchy (like they do to me), `exists` can also interpolate system properties. You can quickly go overboard, and POMs shouldn't know anything about the system upon which a project is built, so tread carefully.

Your woes are indicative of a deeper problem: why is it that only *you* are looking at SonarQube? Software quality is a shared effort, and SonarQube thrives by running automatically in a central location. You probably want to install SonarQube in your CI environment and run an analysis on each build. Then you and your coworkers can just run [SonarQube IDE](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) to check your work before committing.